# If time series $A, B$ and $A, C$ are cointegrated, is $B, C$ also cointegrated? And with similar confidence?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, cointegration

While I am interested in the general case, let's consider the case of three series. So, suppose time series $A, B, C$. If I can show that $A, B$ and $A, C$ are cointegrated with a test statistic $\ge 95\%$ confidence interval level, can I be expect that $B, C$ are cointegrated? Similarly, can I make a good assumption about the strength of the cointegration test statistic, i.e. will the confidence level be similar?

Intuitively I would think good assumptions can be made, but perhaps there is a chance of scenarios where cointegration is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are cointegrated, they're both $I(1)$ but a linear combination of them is $I(0)$. This suggests we should be able to write each of them in this form:

$A = aJ + Z_A$

$B = bJ + Z_B$

where $J$ is $I(1)$ and $Z$'s are $I(0)$.

Now a similar relationship exists between $A$ and $C$; consequently it seems  that $C$ must relate to the *same* integrated component, $J$, otherwise $A$ would have a second $I(1)$ component in it and in that case there wouldn't be a linear combination of $A$ and $B$ that was $I(0)$. So it looks like $C$ must be of the form

$C = cJ + Z_C$

and therefore should be cointegrated with $B$ also.

Edit: I did a bit of additional digging about and I see that apparently (and unsurprisingly) this transitivity is quite well known. It's proved, for example, in Appendix A of [this paper](http://eprints.ucm.es/17404/1/1204.pdf).

It can certainly happen that a test can fail to detect cointegration between $B$ and $C$, even when it should be present.

See for example, Ferré (2004) [1] which uses the Johansen test in just such a setup (using simulation), where $A$ was "driving" the relationship between $B$ and $C$ (in a sense, $A=J$). With that setup, even though cointegration was usually detected between each of the two variables and $A$, it was usually not detected between $B$ and $C$.

(Note, however, that she calls the series X, Y and Z in her paper)

[1] Ferré, M. (2004),
"The Johansen Test and the Transitivity Property,"
*Economics Bulletin*, Vol. 3, No. 27, pp. 1-7

http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=870226

Comment: That is an interesting and surprising result. Thank you for linking to a paper on this topic, it is very helpful for me!

Comment: Interestingly, when I read your question about 20 minutes ago, I didn't actually know the answer (revealing my inexperience with this material, I guess) ---  I was sure it would be possible for the test to fail to find cointegration, but I had no clear idea whether B and C had to really be cointegrated or whether there'd be obvious exceptions to it. It took a good couple of minutes for me to convince myself that they would be cointegrated.

Comment: "It can certainly happen that a test can fail to detect cointegration between B and C, even though it should be present." That is an interesting statement. Is there a protocol to determine if a result is a false negative?

Comment: If there were, wouldn't that just be a better test, since it could tell you when to reject if you didn't? If you're using the best test you know of it would be difficult to identify a better one. In this particular instance there may well be a better way to go about it than the usual test, but I expect you'd have to bring A in in some way and do something with all three together -- so unless you know of the existence of A, how could you know your failure to reject was wrong?

Comment: Haha, yes, it would! Perhaps I am misreading that statement. I interpreted it as implying that they were in fact cointegrated, but the test was unable to determine if the series are cointegrated. If that is the proper reading, this implies there is a method to determine cointegration. I vaguely recall reading about different tests of stationarity, and that they can occasionally disagree. So I was wondering if you were suggesting using an ensemble of verifications.

Comment: If we set it up so that the *processes* are cointegrated, we can observe that we don't always detect it in the resulting observed series. In my answer I explained why Ferre could tell that her processes were really cointegrated - she used simulation to generate the data -- so she was able to guarantee it. The particular circumstances she used in her simulation show that with that setup it's quite common to detect cointegration between A,B and also A,C but common not to detect it in B,C.

Comment: I need to work through the paper in more detail to understand how this was done. Thanks again!